# Nested FOR loop indexing issue - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, indexing

I am having trouble with my indices in a nested for loop. Python is spitting out an index error telling me my index is out of bounds.

Below are my code and subsequent error:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

croot = 1
ctip = 1
span = 1
thetaroot = 0
thetatip = 0
a0root = 0.11
a0tip = 0.11
alpha = 0
alpha0root = -2.5
alpha0tip = -2.5
thetaroot = thetaroot * arctan(1.) / 45.
thetatip = thetatip * arctan(1.) / 45.
alpha = alpha * arctan(1.) / 45.
alpha0root = alpha0root * arctan(1.) / 45.
alpha0tip = alpha0tip * arctan(1.) / 45.
n = 10
theta = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
y = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
c = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
cl = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
alp = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
a = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
rhs = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
b = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
a = np.empty(n, dtype = object)
rhs = rhs[:,None]
b = b[:,None]
a = a[:,None]
#
# Define properties at n span stations
#
pi = 4. * arctan(1.)
for i in range(0,n):
    theta[i] = i * pi / (2. * n)
    y[i] = span * 0.5 * cos(theta[i])
    c[i] = croot + (ctip - croot) * y[i] * 2. / span
    alp[i] = alpha + thetaroot - (alpha0root + (alpha0tip - alpha0root + thetaroot - thetatip) * y[i] * 2. / span)
    a[i] = a0root + (a0tip - a0root) * y[i] * 2. / span

pi = 4. * arctan(1.)
# Set up 2n x 2n system of equations for A1, A3 , ... A2n-1
for j in range(0,n):
    mu = c[j] * a[j] / (4. * span); print('mu=',mu)
    rhs[j,0] = alp[j] * sin(theta[j]) * c[j] * a[j] / (4 * span)
    for i in range(0,n):
        l = 2 * i - 1
        b[j,i] = sin(l * theta[j]) * (mu * l + sin(theta[j]))
```

I then receive the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-b5bd95e69bb5> in <module>()
     45     for i in range(0,n):
     46         l = 2 * i - 1
---> 47         b[j,i] = sin(l * theta[j]) * (mu * l + sin(theta[j]))
     48 
     49 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

How can I effectively call out both indices? In MATLAB, b(j,i) is the normal syntax.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is this numpy - in which case where do you import the relevant libraries

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my script with the imported libraries. Numpy is being used.

Comment: `b` is `(n,1)`.  If something close to this worked in MATLAB its because that language expands an array if indexed beyond the current size.  In `numpy` you have to initialize it to the correct final shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `b = np.empty(n, dtype = object)` with `n=10` makes a one-dimensional array, but you are indexing into it (`b[j,i]`) as though it is a two-dimensional array.

To initialize a 10 by 10 array, you would call `b = np.empty([n, n], dtype = object)`.

EDIT:
I didn't notice this assignment: `b = b[:,None]`
That creates this:

```
>>> [[None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]
 [None]]
```

which is a two-dimensional array, but trying to index past the first element of the inner array (containing just None) is causing your error.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean b = np.empty([n, n], dtype = object) ??

Comment: Oops, yes I did mean that.

Comment: So, since it is trying to index past the first element, what would you suggest as a viable alternative for the nested loop?

Comment: My suggestion was create b as `b = np.empty([n, n], dtype = object)`, then the nested loop should work. (and remove `b = b[:,None]`)

Comment: In doing that, I receive an error stating 'too many indeces'. It points to the line containing rhs[j,i] = alp[j] * sin(theta[j]) * c[j] * a[j] / (4 * span)

Comment: Should i call for rhs[j] instead of rhs[j,1] ?

Comment: Did you change your code? What you have posted above says `rhs[j,0] = alp[j] * sin(theta[j]) * c[j] * a[j] / (4 * span)` ... This works for me, b ends up as a 10 by 10 array containing a bunch of random-looking floats.

Comment: Good catch. Not sure how that happened. It runs now. Thank you for all the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: The only problem is, I need to use linalg.solve in order to solve for a in ab = rhs. This cannot be done because b is now a singular matrix and thus cannot be inverted. Any ideas?